# OAuth not being picked up by PHP after installing it via PECL

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth, pecl

I needed to set up Oauth as part of a PHP project I will be working on.

To do this I ran;

```
sudo pecl install oauth
```

This completed OK and it instructed me to add `extension=oauth.so` to my `php.ini` file, which I did.

I then restarted Apache and ran

```
php -i | grep oauth
```

To see if it was being picked up by PHP, it appears to be as I get this as the result;

```
source version => $Id: oauth.c 325799 2012-05-24 21:07:51Z jawed $
```

But when I run the (CodeIgniter) app I get the error;

```
Fatal error: Class 'Oauth' not found in...
```

Is there a vital step I am missing out?

Comment: run phpinfo() within your app... check for oauth there and the loaded php.ini files

Comment: That was it @AndyJones! Apache was loading in a different php.ini file, once I added it and restarted I was in business! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the comment from @Andy Jones as answer here to remove this question from unanswered questions list:

run phpinfo() within your app... check for oauth there and the loaded php.ini files.